# Use "search" in permalink?

Tags: search, urls, rewrite-rules

I am currently in the process of migrating a custom web app to WordPress and in the custom app, search requests have a URL structure of `mydomain.com/search?q={search criteria}`.

I attempted to add this kind of URL structure to the new WordPress site, but it always redirects back to the site's homepage. My guess is this behavior is due to the fact that search is a Reserved Term and therefore cannot use `search` by itself in the URL.

Can the StackExchange WordPress community please review and suggest how I may be able to pull this off?